# Understanding the reasoning between copy/move constructors and operators

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

I am trying to get the grasp of rvalue references and move semantics with a simple self-made example but I can't understand a specific part. I have created the following class:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) {
        cout << "Def constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(const A& var) {
        cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(A&& var) {
        cout << "Move constructor" << endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& var) {
        cout << "Copy Assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    A& operator=(A&& var) {
        cout << "Move Assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

I tried the following experiments to see if I can predict how the constructors/operators are going to be called:

1. A a1(1) -    The default constructor is going to be called.
   **PREDICTED**.
2. A a2 = a1 - The copy constructor is going to be called. **PREDICTED**.
3. a1 = a2 -  The copy assignment operator is going to be called.
   **PREDICTED**.

Now, I created a simple function that just returns an A object.

```
A helper() {
   return A(1);
}
```

1. A a3 = helper() - The default constructor is going to be called in
   order to create the object that the helper returns. The move
   constructor is not going to be called due to RVO. **PREDICTED**.
2. a3 = helper() - The default constructor is going to be called in
   order to create the object that the helper returns. Then, the move
   assignment operator is going to be called. **PREDICTED**.

Now comes the part I don't understand. I created another function that is completely pointless. It takes an A object by value and it just returns it.

```
A helper_alt(A a) {
    return a;
}
```

1. A a4 = helper_alt(a1) - This will call the copy constructor, to
   actually copy the object a1 in the function and then the move
   constructor. **PREDICTED**.
2. a4 = helper_alt(a1) - This will call the copy constructor, to
   actually copy the object a1 in the function and then I thought that
   the move assignment operator is going to be called BUT as I saw,
   first, the move constructor is called and then the move assignment
   operator is called. **HAVE NO IDEA**.

Please, if any of what I said is wrong or you feel I might have not understood something, feel free to correct me.

My actual *question*: **In the last case, why is the move constructor being called and then the move assignment operator, instead of just the move assignment operator?**

Comment: This is because `a` is the *parameter* of `helper_alt`. NRVO cannot be applied to function parameters. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? I understand that NRVO will not be applied but why do we have the following order? 1) copy constructor (I understand this, it happens in order to copy the object because we pass it to the function by value). 2) move constructor (why?). 3) move assignment. Shouldn't 2 be completely skipped?

Comment: Let's try again. Skipping that move constructor would be NRVO. NRVO cannot be applied to function parameters. Do you want to try a function that returns a variable which is not a parameter, and compare what happens in the two cases?

Comment: @kerk_pilos just FYI, `A(int a)` is not a [*default* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), it is a [*converting* constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/converting_constructor) (you are *converting* an `int` to an `A`). If `int a` had a default value assigned, ie `A(int a = 0)` then this would be a suitable default constructor.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Congratulations, you found a core issue of C++!

There are still a lot of discussions around the behavior you see with your example code.

There are suggestions like:

```
A&& helper_alt(A a) {
    std::cout << ".." << std::endl;
    return std::move(a);
}
```

This will do what you want, simply use the move assignment but emits a warning from g++ "warning: reference to local variable 'a' returned", even if the variable goes immediately out of scope.

Already other people found that problem and this is already made a [c++ standard language core issue](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1148)

Interestingly the issue was already found in 2010 but not solved until now...

To give you an answer to your question "**In the last case, why is the move constructor being called and then the move assignment operator, instead of just the move assignment operator?**" is, that also C++ committee does not have an answer until now. To be precise, there is a proposed solution and this one is accepted but until now not part of the language.

From: [Comment Status](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3296.html#DE11)

> Amend paragraph 34 to explicitly exclude function parameters from copy elision. Amend paragraph 35 to include function parameters as eligible for move-construction.

Comment: Are you sure that your suggested approach does not return a dangling reference?

Comment: That was not my suggestion, it was found in a discussion. I did not say it is a valid solution, it is simply what was found on a lot other places. The solution is quite clear: Fix the language :-)

Answer (score 2):

consider the below example. I have compiled the sample code using -fno-elide-constructors flag to prevent RVO optimizations:
`g++ -fno-elide-constructors -o test test.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A(int a) {
        cout << "Def constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(const A& var) {
        cout << "Copy constructor" << endl;
    }

    A(A&& var) {
        cout << "Move constructor" << endl;
    }

    A& operator=(const A& var) {
        cout << "Copy Assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

    A& operator=(A&& var) {
        cout << "Move Assignment" << endl;
        return *this;
    }
};

A a_global(1);

A helper_alt(A a) {
    return a;
}

A helper_a_local(A a) {
    A x(1);
    return x;
}

A helper_a_global(A a) {
    return a_global;
}

int main(){
    A a1(1);
    A a4(4);
    std::cout << "================= helper_alt(a1) ==================" << std::endl;
    a4 = helper_alt(a1);
    std::cout << "=============== helper_a_local()   ================" << std::endl;
    a4 = helper_a_local(a1);
    std::cout << "=============== helper_a_global()  ================" << std::endl;
    a4 = helper_a_global(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

This will result in the below output:

```
Def constructor
Def constructor
Def constructor
================= helper_alt(a1) ==================
Copy constructor
Move constructor
Move Assignment
=============== helper_a_local()   ================
Copy constructor
Def constructor
Move constructor
Move Assignment
=============== helper_a_global()  ================
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Move Assignment
```

In simple words, C++ constructs a new temporary object (`rvalue`) when the return type is not a reference, which results in calling Move or Copy constructor depending on the value category and the lifetime of the returned object.
Anyway, I think the logic behind calling the constructor is that you are not working with reference, and returned identity should be construed first, either by copy or move constructor, depending on the returned `value category` or lifetime of the return object. As another example:

```
A helper_move_vs_copy(A a) {
    // Call the Copy Constructor
    A b = a;
    // Call the Move Constructor, Due to the end of 'a' lifetime
    return a;
}

int main(){
    A a1(1);
    A a2(4);
    std::cout << "=============== helper_move_vs_copy()  ================" << std::endl;
    helper_move_vs_copy(a1);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
Def constructor
Def constructor
=============== helper_move_vs_copy()  ================
Copy constructor
Copy constructor
Move constructor
```

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category):

> an xvalue (an “eXpiring” value) is a glvalue that denotes an object whose resources can be reused;

At last, it is the job of `RVO` to decrease unnecessary moves and copies by optimization of the code, which can even result in an optimized binary for basic programmers!